# C++ enum of type char, ignored by the compiler or unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c++, enums

I did a little test with an enum, here is what I have:

```
enum anyoldname : char
{
    aa = 'a', ab = 'b', ac = 'c', ad = 'd'
};

int main()
{

    anyoldname i_have_an_enum_here = aa; // Would expect i_have_an_enum_here to be of type char?

    std::cout << i_have_an_enum_here << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is: `98`, unless I cast explicitly to char like so:

```
std::cout << (char)i_have_an_enum_here;
```

Or change `anyoldname` to `char`.

Why is the value `98` printed instead of `b` ?

By the way `sizeof()` returns `1`, ie; 1 byte, a `char`.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `aa`, and `aa == 'a'` is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without** the cast, the compiler first searches for an appropriate member function of `std::ostream`, and it finds one -- the one for an `int`. So it implicitly converts your 1-byte number of type `anyoldname` to an `int` and calls the member function.

Compiling your program with g++ 4.8.1, two definitions for `ostream::operator<<` are seen:

```
     U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@@GLIBCXX_3.4
     U std::ostream::operator<<(int)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

The first one is for `endl` and the second one is for your enum.

**With** the explicit cast to char, the compiler is able to find a perfect match in the global `std::operator<<` function that takes an `ostream` and a `char` as an input. It then uses this function rather than doing an implicit cast (to an `int` again) in order to call an `ostream` member function.

The two symbols become:

```
     U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@@GLIBCXX_3.4
     U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)
```

and your values are printed as characters rather than their decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to read The C++ Standard (I have only C++11 right now) section 7.2 paragraph 5:

> Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types. Each enumeration also has an
>   underlying type. The underlying type can be explicitly specified using enum-base; if not explicitly specified,...

Particularly this mean that your `anyoldname` actually a **separate** type which size the same as `char` (because its underlying type specified explicitly in a declaration). So, no reason to be implicitly convertible to `char`!

Comment: This is true, but the compiler must have implicitly converted the enum type to *something*. That's why he got a print out, rather than a compiler error complaining about the lack of an `operator<<` for the new type.